# How can JS code remove blank string between other strings in text?

Tags: javascript

For JS, an array of text is set in the **`arr`** variable:

```
let arr = ["When I consider every thing that grows",
"",
"Holds in perfection but a little moment,",
"",
"That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows",
"",
"Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;"];
```

How to remove the empty lines from it, and that it remains as an array, but without the empty strings:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a boolean filter for this:

```
arr.filter(Boolean)
```

Full Code:

```js
let arr = [
  "When I consider every thing that grows",
  "",
  "Holds in perfection but a little moment,",
  "",
  "That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows",
  "",
  "Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;"
];
console.log(arr.filter(Boolean));
```

Gives me:

```
[
  "When I consider every thing that grows",
  "Holds in perfection but a little moment,",
  "That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows",
  "Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;"
]
```